# Unexpected behaviour of addListenerForSingleValueEvent

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to simply determine if a user exists by a given id in our firebase database. 
The database has the following simple structure and content:

```
{
  "users" : {
    "-KTYqHtVJ4Q4LtDl0uTv" : {
      "userID" : "0200000262",
      "storeName" : "Stapples hhbjngg",
      "userName" : "ris983"
    }
}
```

For this I added a listener for single value event on the database for the given node.

The problem is that this listener fails to detect correctly the user after the user was added I would think that this is because I didn't understand correctly the behaviour.

What makes the situation more confusing is that if I am adding an other ChildEventListener which is completely independent from the first listener, the first listener is functioning perfectly.

In first case dataSnapshot value is: :

```
DataSnapshot { key = users, value = null }
```

If the second listener is enabled, then datasnapshot correctly contains the content:

```
DataSnapshot { key = users, value = {-KTZ78jMYR0CiYiNHVvo={userID=0200000262, userName=ris983, storeName=Stapples hhbjngg}} }
```

Here I pass the source code. 
Thanks in advance.

```
 private  void retrieveFirebaseUserByID(final String userID, final FireBaseUserListener fireBaseUserListener) {
        final DatabaseReference usersDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users");
        usersDatabase.orderByChild("userID").equalTo(userID).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
                new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                            Iterator<DataSnapshot> iter = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator();
                            while (iter.hasNext()) {
                                DataSnapshot storeDataSnapshot = iter.next();

                                String firebaseUserKey = storeDataSnapshot.getKey();
                                FirebaseUser firebaseUser = storeDataSnapshot.getValue(FirebaseUser.class);
                                fireBaseUserListener.userFound(firebaseUser);
                            }
                        } else {
                            fireBaseUserListener.userNotFound();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                        fireBaseUserListener.userListenerError();
                    }
                }
        );

        //Seems that without this listener(childeventlistener) the previous listener(eventlistener) is not working correctly but it results in not found even if the node with the given userID is existent.
         usersDatabase.orderByChild("userID").equalTo(userID).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener(){

            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String prevChildKey) {
                usersDatabase.removeEventListener(this);
                String userID = dataSnapshot.getKey();
                FirebaseUser firebaseUser = dataSnapshot.getValue(FirebaseUser.class);
                firebaseUser.setFirebaseID(userID);
                fireBaseUserListener.userFound(firebaseUser);
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {}

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {}

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {}

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
        });


    }
```

UPDATE

After enabling firebase DEBUG logs it seems that the issue is coming from persistence capability of firebase. 
It seems that even if the connection is available firebase decides to fire the valueevent with nul value. As this query was done previously.

This seems to be very clear from the logs:

```
Persistence: Starting transaction.
Persistence: Saved new tracked query in 1ms
Persistence: Loaded 0 tracked queries keys for tracked queries [256] in 0ms
Persistence: Loaded a total of 2 rows for a total of 6 nodes at /users34 in 1ms (Query: 0ms, Loading: 1ms, Serializing: 0ms)
Persistence: Set 0 tracked query keys for tracked query 256 in 0ms
PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Listening on users34 (params: {i=sapID, sp=0200000262, ep=0200000262})
PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Adding listen query: users34 (params: {i=sapID, sp=0200000262, ep=0200000262})
Connection: conn_1 - Sending data: {d={a=q, r=7, b={q={i=sapID, sp=0200000262, ep=0200000262}, h=, p=users34, t=3}}, t=d}
WebSocket: ws_1 - Reset keepAlive. Remaining: 30438
Persistence: Transaction completed. Elapsed: 8ms
EventRaiser: Raising 1 event(s)
EventRaiser: Raising /users34: VALUE: null
FirebaseUtils.retrieveFirebaseUserBySapID.addListenerForSingleValueEvent.onDataChange: DataSnapshot { key = users34, value = null }
```

So it is still unclear why firebase returns the persisted node even when connection is available and also it is unclear how to avoid this type of situations or possible errors in the future having the persistence enabled, the need to create an extra listener just for the first to be working seems more like a hack and not a solution.

Comment: The posted JSON doesn't appear to be correct.  It contains member `sapID`.  The code references `userID`.  Please post the correct JSON.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. You are correct

Comment: I created test data with the same structure.  Copied and ran your code with version 9.6.1.  I can't reproduce the behavior you are reporting.

Comment: If you called your model FirebaseUser it may be confused with FirebaseUser class in the firebase library. better change it to another name

Comment: And why do u set userId again. FirebaseUser must contain it according to ur structure

Comment: Thank you ugboz, you are right using FirebaseUser is confusing although I can't see why it should cause an error. I will fix that.

Comment: Thanks qbix for the efforts, I try to create a complete separate example and upload that for you.

Comment: Ahh and uguboz, we are setting firebaseID because that is not the userID which is used in the json node, but actually it is the key of the node in the firebase db as you see from the "datasnapshot.getKey()" call. We simply decided to include the key from firebase in our internal structure as it is simplifies the handling of these objects later on.

Comment: So I have spent quite long time to try to reproduce this issue on a separate application which could be published, but could not achieve. The issue was not appearing. Actually I arrived to  use the basically the same classes in one app as in the other and the issue was happening in the original app and not in the example. I will continue investigating as I see this issue as vital as it affects basic functionality (we can not be sure if a user exist already) and our decision is to choose firebase as secondary database is now in question. Any help would be more than welcome. I am lost with this.