# How to debug Firebase issues by Wireshark?

Tags: android, debugging, encryption, firebase, wireshark

I am trying to debug a Firebase issue where for the same query I am receiving different responses.

The issue has been posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39933400/unexpected-behaviour-of-addlistenerforsinglevalueevent)

As I couldn't reproduce the issue in a separate example application. 
I was was wondering if it would be possible to disable HTTPS encryption and access Firebase temporally on debug apps, using HTTP without transit encryption.

This would allow to compare the exact data sent and received by the different apps so that the issue could be addressed. Without encryption, Wireshark or similar tools could be used to compare traffic sent and received by different apps which always proves to be very useful in these kind of issues.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to get content from/to your Firebase Database over an unencrypted connection.

To see the traffic between a client and the Firebase Database you can simply enable debug logging in your Android code:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setLogLevel(Logger.Level.INFO)
```

See the [Firebase reference documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/FirebaseDatabase.html#setLogLevel(com.google.firebase.database.Logger.Level)) and this question: [Debugging Firebase Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37817416/debugging-firebase-database).

Comment: Thanks. This is also helpful. Interface capture would have been better in any case, but I understand then that it is not possible.